# How to parse data from mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using change stream to see the changes in mongodb. I retrieve the document in the below format, now how to parse in strings. I need the value of $oid and name

Full document is

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5c60f87a9ea5deac53457e9c"}, "name": "freddy"}
```

I am using Java code

```
MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<BasicDBObject>> cursor1 = collection.watch().iterator();
System.out.println("Connection Completely Established 4");

for(int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
{
    ChangeStreamDocument<BasicDBObject> next1 = cursor1.next();

    System.out.println("Operation Type is " + next1.getOperationType());
    System.out.println("Database Name is" + next1.getDatabaseName());
    System.out.println("Full Document is " + next1.getFullDocument());
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the document string then you can use a method to acquire the data needed. The **getBetween()** method below will retrieve the information you want from your provided document string, here is how it might be used to achieve this:

```
String docString = "Full Document is {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5c60f87a9ea5deac53457e9c\"}, \"name\": \"freddy\"}";
String oid = getBetween(docString, "$oid\": \"", "\"}")[0];
String name = getBetween(docString, "name\": \"", "\"}")[0];

System.out.println(oid);
System.out.println(name);
```

The Console Window will display:

```
5c60f87a9ea5deac53457e9c
freddy
```

Here is the **getBetween()** method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves any string data located between the supplied string leftString
 * parameter and the supplied string rightString parameter.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * <p>
 * This method will return all instances of a substring located between the
 * supplied Left String and the supplied Right String which may be found
 * within the supplied Input String.<br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to look for substring(s) in.
 *
 * @param leftString  (String) What may be to the Left side of the substring
 *                    we want within the main input string. Sometimes the
 *                    substring you want may be contained at the very
 *                    beginning of a string and therefore there is no
 *                    Left-String available. In this case you would simply
 *                    pass a Null String ("") to this parameter which
 *                    basically informs the method of this fact. Null can
 *                    not be supplied and will ultimately generate a
 *                    NullPointerException.
 *
 * @param rightString (String) What may be to the Right side of the
 *                    substring we want within the main input string.
 *                    Sometimes the substring you want may be contained at
 *                    the very end of a string and therefore there is no
 *                    Right-String available. In this case you would simply
 *                    pass a Null String ("") to this parameter which
 *                    basically informs the method of this fact. Null can
 *                    not be supplied and will ultimately generate a
 *                    NullPointerException.
 *
 * @param options     (Optional - Boolean - 2 Parameters):<pre>
 *
 *      ignoreLetterCase    - Default is false. This option works against the
 *                            string supplied within the leftString parameter
 *                            and the string supplied within the rightString
 *                            parameter. If set to true then letter case is
 *                            ignored when searching for strings supplied in
 *                            these two parameters. If left at default false
 *                            then letter case is not ignored.
 *
 *      trimFound           - Default is true. By default this method will trim
 *                            off leading and trailing white-spaces from found
 *                            sub-string items. General sentences which obviously
 *                            contain spaces will almost always give you a white-
 *                            space within an extracted sub-string. By setting
 *                            this parameter to false, leading and trailing white-
 *                            spaces are not trimmed off before they are placed
 *                            into the returned Array.</pre>
 *
 * @return (1D String Array) Returns a Single Dimensional String Array
 *         containing all the sub-strings found within the supplied Input
 *         String which are between the supplied Left String and supplied
 *         Right String.
 */
public String[] getBetween(String inputString, String leftString, String rightString, boolean... options) {
    // Return nothing if nothing was supplied.
    if (inputString.equals("") || (leftString.equals("") && rightString.equals(""))) {
        return null;
    }

    // Prepare optional parameters if any supplied.
    // If none supplied then use Defaults...
    boolean ignoreCase = false; // Default.
    boolean trimFound = true;   // Default.
    if (options.length > 0) {
        if (options.length >= 1) {
            ignoreCase = options[0];
        }
        if (options.length >= 2) {
            trimFound = options[1];
        }
    }

    // Remove any ASCII control characters from the
    // supplied string (if they exist).
    String modString = inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");

    // Establish a List String Array Object to hold
    // our found substrings between the supplied Left
    // String and supplied Right String.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Use Pattern Matching to locate our possible
    // substrings within the supplied Input String.
    String regEx = Pattern.quote(leftString)
            + (!rightString.equals("") ? "(.*?)" : "(.*)?")
            + Pattern.quote(rightString);
    if (ignoreCase) {
        regEx = "(?i)" + regEx;
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(modString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Add the found substrings into the List.
        String found = matcher.group(1);
        if (trimFound) {
            found = found.trim();
        }
        list.add(found);
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```